# Sending json object with android doesn't work

Tags: android, json, httpclient

I want to send json object to my WebService and read the response but my code dosn't work. JSON Object was created but propably not send. WebService not received this object.

my activity:

```
package com.example.secapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.*;
import java.io.InputStream;





public class dwa extends Activity {


    Context context;


    TextView imie;
    TextView wiek;
    Button przycisk;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wynik);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String URL = "http://192.168.0.105:8080/2WS/test/login";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            json.put("login",bundle.getString("login") );
            json.put("password",bundle.getString("pass") );
            System.out.println(json.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            if(response!=null){
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        wiek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);



        String imieString = bundle.getString("login");
        String wiekString = bundle.getString("pass");


        imie.setText(imieString);
        wiek.setText(wiekString);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help and sorry for my english. :)

Comment: Try the request from a web browser and see if the web service is responding.

Comment: Yup, web service is working and responding.

Comment: How about from a browser on the device? The problem may be with getting a connection to that address rather than anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate an api in your application use retrofit : square.github.io/retrofit/

Hope it helps.